# Parking domains redirect to landing page wordpress htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I hope everyone doing great, I need help, I use Wordpress last version, I need define for my web site my principal default domain example MyWordpressSite.com and all parking domains go to MyWordpressSite.com/LandingPage/ any way to define all domains in one single line and redirect to the LandingPage? I dont want define domain by domain any way in htaccess or other options?

Thanks in advances for any help!

Regards
Manny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a negative pattern, assuming you're on Apache:

```
RewriteEngine on
#usually need next line though modify if WordPress is running in a subfolder
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^your\.domain\.tld$
RewriteRule ^ http://your.domain.tld/landing-page/ [L,R=301]
```

Any request to your non-primary domain will be permanently redirected to that page.